# How to decrypt a SAML Response in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, saml, adfs

I have SAML Response and Metadata URL provided by Client (Identity Provider). How I (Service Provider) Can decrypt the SAML Response

Below is the SAML Response

```
<samlp:Response ID="_17222aef-2970-44d1-aae6-1c25187c4319" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-06-29T10:23:12.036Z" Destination="https://ssotest-1246771484.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/ssotest/index.html" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
  InResponseTo="a351b3fi19a2024838868e374da59j6" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://yyy.xxx.com/adfs/zzz/trust</Issuer>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
  </samlp:Status>
  <EncryptedAssertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
          </e:EncryptionMethod>
          <KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
            <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=apollo, OU=R&amp;D, O=RM5 Software Oy, L=Helsinki, S=Uusimaa, C=FI</ds:X509IssuerName>
            <ds:X509SerialNumber>1357039681</ds:X509SerialNumber>
          </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
      <e:CipherData>
        <e:CipherValue>f6yX7d1FF4eHtj79WRxJ/xga3qhUASk79sTHWDfKW/bHbIGL+UVwBIdQIh21AMbLN/1cgiVCps7UBAoaipew7JQCq1EYQR/ipFO7Wcmoqs5V1h/KwBgNdhT/L/TqAacIz9QoRPkNhxsDAKMvdj9wwPZhYHGvqC1cFgrMZjMS4r1VlF2qh2TgQVgv9PjA234dZfNLTUmu1WNRjs30mtcZAZtnwB8A6sUwQsJCSfKfXoTcEAYrD2Am+9FQdHBnrZ3HwtH1gkbe0pAYtEPqX+yzRm7wtsMLj9F4+PoE1Ax3Ju3kpPiV5u1au1CCJG8CzuxbswFII4npKlwjuKm9y7A8YA==</e:CipherValue>
      </e:CipherData>
    </e:EncryptedKey>
  </KeyInfo>
  <xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue>
  </xenc:CipherData>
</xenc:EncryptedData>
```

Comment: Usually, the service provider gives an IdP a public key associated with its encryption private key... I take it you don't have the private key for this certificate (`CN=apollo, OU=R&amp;D, O=RM5 Software Oy, L=Helsinki, S=Uusimaa, C=FI`)?

Comment: Hi Andrew , we didn't provide any key to the IdP

Comment: @sam mhatre SAML IdP needs to use the public key of your SAML Service Provider to encrypt SAML assertion. If you did NOT provide any key to the SAML IdP, please report this SAML encryption issue to SAML IdP development team, because SAML IdP should NOT encrypt SAML assertion without public key of SAML SP.

Answer (score 0):

How encryption scenario works in SAML: identity provider encrypts some elements of the SAML response with service provider's public key. The service provider decrypts using the private key that corresponds to the public key used to encrypt. In other words, the service provider needs to own a keypair - private key and public key - for this use case to work.

Assuming you have the private key for decryption, you just need to decide on the implementation approach. Rolling your own is technically possible but unlikely to succeed. For .NET we recommend either [Sustainsys](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) or [ITFoxtec](https://www.itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2), both are OSS and support decryption.

Comment: Basically a .NET SAML library. ComponentSpace is another candidate.